# how does backtracking for n times after the nth iteration in bellman ford gurantees that a node in a negative cycle found

Tags: graph-theory, bellman-ford

In the Bellman-Ford algorithm, when detecting a negative cycle and printing the cycle during the final iteration, the step of backtracking through parents n times ensures the identification of a node within the negative cycle. This guarantees that the negative cycle will be correctly reconstructed and printed.  why and how??

I have tried drawing graphs and applying this method. It works, but I could not figure out why??